# Empy req.body in NodeJs, Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to send a json to my nodeJs app through POST Method in body.
For that I'm using POSTMAN to create the request, with the proper consnt-type header and body JSON Rows. Tho the message back is "OK" in console the req.body is {} empty.
Would you have an idea what's wrong in my code?

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { Client } = require('pg');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// create application/json parser
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const dbSchema = 'public';

const client = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'postgres',
    password: '123123',
    port: 5432,
});

client.connect();

/* =========== Some Initialize staff =============== */

// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

/* =========== FROM HERE =============== */

app.post('/post-test', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    console.log('Got body:', req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).send('Get Ready for something awesome!\n');
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0qLh.png)
[image]
[image]

Comment: I usually use - `route.use(express.json());route.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));` In your case the `route` is `app`. New versions of Express don't have to use `body-parser`

Comment: When I added the following lines: app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));  started to get the following error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 92

Comment: what is the version of express u r using?

Comment: express": "^4.17.1",

Comment: `urlencodedParser ` is for? something seems wrong with the input JSON as shown in postman screenshot?

Comment: actually, I removed it as it doesn't make any sense in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `app.use(bodyParser.json());`, in your code `const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()` this is not used.

Update: Or you can apply `jsonParser` middleware directly to the post route:

```
app.post("/post-test", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Got body:", req.body);
  res.json({ ...req.body });
});
```

Comment: I added: app.use(bodyParser.json()); tho started to get the following error while running the request: Unexpected token in JSON at position 92

Comment: could you  provide your body in postman instead of the image ?

Comment: I added "jsonParser" in the app.post(...), and get the same error: Unexpected token in JSON at position 92

Comment: {
   "username":  "newHere",
   "fullname": "homeless",
   "email": "alwaysYoung@gmail.com", 
   "psw": "password",    
   "inviterId": 1,
}

Comment: remove the comma `,` after `"inviterId": 1`

Comment: Have removed the comma  after  **"inviterId: 1"**, that didn't solve the issue: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 95'

Comment: what happen if you just send `{ "username":  "newHere" }` with postman ?

Comment: Hmm It worked well, it returned the req.body, tho anyway with an error in console: _Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client_

Comment: Ok, so the object sent in postman wasn't well formatted,  postman was already complaining in line 4! for the `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` no idea, i  tested the code locally  and  it's ok ..

Comment: the error was related with  fact that I forgot to remove a res and both were called same time res.json({ ...req.body });
    // res.sendStatus(200);

Comment: May I ask, so if res.json({ ...req.body }); was the solution, then how could I apply it when I want to introduce the req.body parameters to a select ?

Comment: ` res.json({ ...req.body });` was only for debugging, `then how could I apply it when I want to introduce the req.body parameters to a select ?` this is not clear to me ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure what is happening so, I am posting the code that works for me -

```
    let express = require('express'); 
    let app = express();
    const authorRoute = express.Router();
    authorRoute.use(express.json());
    authorRoute.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    authorRoute.post('/post-test', async (req, res) => {//req.body});
    app.use(authorRoute);
```

Also, make sure to test with a well-formed JSON.
version "express": "^4.17.1",